# Jolokia - where is jolokia-access.xml?

Tags: jolokia

I recently started to use Jolokia (on Weblogic server on a Windows VM) and it was fine (i.e. I could access to http://:/jolokia/version). However, after setting up credentials for an user, I find that I couldn't access to http://:/jolokia/version and it returned 403 Forbidden error. After reading through this page (https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html), the issue seems related to jolokia-access.xml. I tried to find it on server (Windows VM) but failed. I also tried to search for it online but couldn't find it either.

Could you please let me know where the file is? If I need to create the file, where (i.e. path) should I put it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to my question above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in the `conf` directory in the activemq installation directory:

```
c:\<ACTIVEMQ_DIR>\conf\jolokia-access.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

this file is there  in this path:

```
 c:<ACTIVEMQ_DIR>\webapps\api\WEB-INF\classes\jolokia-access.xml
```